# Name of movie about people who have died and are waiting to move on (to heaven or a new life)

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to find the name of a film about people who have died and are waiting to move on..

I think the film is 15-30 years old.

They are not yet in heaven - Their lives are replayed and they are judged. After the viewings they will either go on to heaven (in a bus, if I recall!) or they will be reincarnated and have to live another life, in the hopes of living well enough to be sent on to heaven next time around.

While in this purgatory, a man and a woman fall in love. Towards the end of the film she is sent on to heaven, while he is told he needs to live another life.  He's not happy about this idea and tries to force his way on to her bus, to be with her.

That's about all I can remember - Hope it's enough to identify the film!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Defending your life (1991) starring Albert Brooks and Meryl Streep:

[IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101698/) I remember Rip Torn was the lawyer assigned to defend Albert Brooks, it was pretty funny.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you. No idea what made me think of this. Woke up at 3am recalling fragments of a film from 20+ years ago. How bizarre.

Comment: I have oddly fond memories of this movie.   It does help that Rip Torn was in it.

Comment: @pooter03 I liked this movie too, especially when the prosecution started to present their evidence and there were multiple flashback scenes showing him being afraid and generally messing up

Comment: Rip Torn.  LOL.  He got arrested up by me a year or so ago, I guess he lives somewhere nearby.

Comment: @JohnnyBones he is very good in this film, his personality suited the role really well, as did Albert Brooks, just found a classic scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DufE-dcQ70k

Comment: @EdChum I suppose I was drawn to the idea of eating as much as you want of the best food you've ever tasted. :)